# Why is this HTML Canvas clearRect() acting this way?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I've been working on a hangman HTML canvas project. I'm almost complete, but I need a way to write some text on the screen to output the used characters data. I've encountered a weird problem using the clearRect() function, and I cannot understand what is wrong.

This is a portion of my code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

var badStore = []; //this gets filled with used data
var canvasText = []; //this gets filled with characters that are supposed to be outputted to the canvas after the elements are joined with .join()

(function initialize() {
    c.fillText(canvasText.join(" "), canvas.width/2, canvas.height - 70);
    c.font = "20px Comic Sans MS";
    c.fillStyle = "black";
    c.textAlign = "center";
    c.fillText(`Used: `, canvas.width/2, canvas.height - 20);
    c.strokeStyle = 'black';
}
.
.
.
```

When a correct letter is entered using window.addEventListener() and added to (canvasText), the following code is executed:

```
c.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
c.fillStyle = "black";
c.textAlign = "center";
c.clearRect(0, canvas.height - 100, canvas.width, canvas.height - 70);
c.fillText(canvasText.join(" "), canvas.width/2, canvas.height - 70);

.
.
.
```

When an incorrect letter is entered using window.addEventListener() and added to (badStore), the following code is executed:

```
c.font = "20px Comic Sans MS";
c.fillStyle = "black";
c.textAlign = "center";
c.clearRect(0, canvas.height - 40, canvas.width, canvas.height - 20);
c.fillText(`Used: ${badStore}`, canvas.width/2, canvas.height - 20);
.
.
.
```

When I type a correct letter, the canvas rewrites the first c.fillText() section with the inputted character.
Likewise, when I type an incorrect letter, the canvas rewrites the second c.fillText() section with the inputted character.

However, when I type an incorrect letter and then a correct letter, the second c.fillText() disappears. Can someone explain what is happening here and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Could you also provide how you add things to your arrays? That's seems pretty integral.

Comment: The params are `clearRect( x, y, width, height )`. Sounds like you expected `x2, y2` instead.